# Dynamic nested lists using nested foreach not working

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jstl

I'm using JSF 2.2, Primefaces 3.5, with JSTL 1.1 tags, here is a sample of the code:

```
<c:forEach items="${backingBean.myObjects}" var="Object" varStatus="objIndex">
    <p:panel id="bo_#{objIndex.index}">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
           <h:outputText value="#{Object.className}" />
           <p:commandButton value="Add Field" actionListener="#{backingBean.addField(objIndex.index)}" update="bo_#{objIndex.index}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <c:forEach items="${Object.fields}" var="field" varStatus="fIndex">
                <h:inputText id="fName_#{objIndex.index}_#{fIndex.index}" value="#{field.name}">
                <h:inputText id="fVal_#{objIndex.index}_#{fIndex.index}" value="#{field.value}">
                <p:commandButton value="X" actionListener="#{backingBean.deleteObjectField(objIndex.index, fIndex.index)}" update="bo_#{objIndex.index}"/>
            </c:forEach>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</c:forEach>
```

This code is used to show a dynamic list of objects that contains a dynamic list of fields, the user can add a field or delete it.

The problem is that, when the user deletes a field which is inside a `bo_#{objIndex.index}` panel, so I update this panel only, but all of the panels below have a duplicated fields IDs (this ID is generated in the above code as follows `fName_#{objIndex.index}_#{fIndex.index}` so it's supposed to be unique,

For ex. Instead of having three fields with IDs `fName_1_0`, `fname_1_1`, `fname_1_2` in a panel with `ID bo_1`, after deleting a field from `panel bo_0`, it will becomes `fName_1_0`, `fname_1_0`, `fname_1_1`) in the generated HTML code which causes me some problems.

Comment: Use `<ui:repeat value="${backingBean.myObjects}" var="Object" varStatus="objIndex">` instead of `c:forEach`.

Comment: I tried using ui:repeat but I was unable update any component by ID in an AJAX call, also I have tried p:datalist but the problem is that i need to know the exact component ID, as in another part of the page i'm using an overlay panel (which needs to know the exact component ID in the for attribute), and while searching as i understood that c:foreach is the right choice as it works on the build time while others work on the rendering time.